# Qt Cannot convert QPaintDevice to QImage

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qimage

This sounds like silly, but I cannot take a screenshot of a QwebView.

```
QImage image(view.page()->viewportSize(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(image); // Here is the error. See below
view.page()->mainFrame()->render(&painter);
painter.end();
image.save("out.png");
```

And the error msg is,

```
mainwindow.cpp:115: error: no matching function for call to 'QPainter::begin(QImage&)'
candidate is bool QPainter::begin(QPaintDevice*)
```

What I know is ,QPaintDevice is the base of QPaint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks from the error that you need to pass `image` by pointer:

```
painter.begin(&image);
```

Comment: Ooops! Thanks. I was looking for probable candidate on the console and didn't find that. :)

Answer (score 3):

The error message told you: the method `begin` requires a pointer to a drawing surface, and not a reference. Try doing:

```
painter.begin(&image);
```